# Начать каждое предложение с заглавной буквы средствами css

Tags: html, css

Хочу чтобы каждое **предложение** начиналось с заглавной буквы. Какими средствами css пользоваться?
`text-transform` поднимает либо все, либо каждое **слово**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На чистом CSS такое сделать нельзя. Либо заворачивайте каждое предложение в отдельный `div` и используйте псевдокласс `:first-letter`, либо прикручивайте JavaScript.

Comment: Спасибо, все понял. Сделал так
.entry-title::first-letter { text-transform: capitalize !important; }

Comment: А Вам не кажется, что Вы занимаетесь ерундой? Нет, к @fori1ton претензий нет, он ответил на Ваш вопрос - предложил варианты. Но какая необходимость грузить код таким количеством div'ов - по одному на каждое предложение? Не проще ли прописать ручками?


На мой взгляд, каждое предложение заворачивать в div - изврат и это еще мягко сказано!

Answer (score 0):

С помощью только `css` никак

Answer (score 0):

Пробуй:

```
P:first-letter {text-transform: capitalize;}
```

Comment: И за что меня минсанули? :)  Разве это не работает?

Answer (score 0):

С помощью css можно изменить строку только в блочных объектах, заголовках и параграфах.

Делаем первую букву Прописной, в строке в формате кодировки символов UTF-8, с помощью PHP:

```
    $title = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($content, 0, 1, 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8'). mb_substr($content, 1, null, 'UTF-8');
    echo $title;
```

Comment: UTF-8 это не формат, а кодировка. Почему первая буква в этой кодировке заглавная?

Comment: Unicode Transformation Format

Comment: @woodsleaf 1. Для строчных элементов можно использовать display:inline-block; 2. Зачем для этой цели использовать PHP???

Comment: Я проверял span с параметром display: inline-block; И знаете что уважаемый DaemonHK, не сработало. По сути своей сайт для поиска решений, и я просто дополнил.